# mkdir() in php is setting folder permission to 755 But I Need 777?

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

I am trying to create a folder on my server using php when i set it to 0777 it comes out as 755?

```
mkdir($create_path, 0777);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
$old_umask = umask(0);
mkdir($create_path, 0777);
umask($old_umask);
```

http://php.net/umask

Comment: Why do you set a `$old_umask = umask(0);` and then `umask($old_umask);`? because setting it once on top is enough why are you setting it again at final?

Comment: @Airy old question but for reference - from the docs:

umask() sets PHP's umask to mask & 0777 and returns the old umask. When PHP is being used as a server module, the umask is restored when each request is finished.

 - Meaning he resets the umask to its original state by doing this.

Answer (score 6):

This really works for me!, you should close now this question!

1. Create the directory!
2. Give 777 permissions!

   ```
   $estructure = '../files/folderName';

   if(!mkdir($estructure, 0777, true)){
       echo "<br/><br/>ERROR: Fail to create the folder...<br/><br/>"; 
   }  else echo "<br/><br/>!! Folder Created...<br/><br/>";

   chmod($estructure, 0777);
   ```
3. Enjoy it!

Comment: In addition, second argument of `mkdir()` is **NOT** applied recursively. So, You need to change permissions using `chmod()` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php
// files will create as -rw-------
umask(0);
// create a file, eg fopen()

chmod('/path/to/directory', 0777);
?>
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php#100198)

Comment: You should reset it back to the previous value. Strange things could happen otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The umask of the process is set to 0022. You'll need to set it to 0 if you want to create something with those two write bits set.