# Creating a folder when I run file_put_contents()

Tags: php

I have uploaded a lot of images from the website, and need to organize files in a better way.
Therefore, I decide to create a folder by months.

```
$month  = date('Yd')
file_put_contents("upload/promotions/".$month."/".$image, $contents_data);
```

after I tried this one, I get error result.

> Message: file_put_contents(upload/promotions/201211/ang232.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

If I tried to put only file in exist folder, it worked. However, it failed to create a new folder.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

[`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) does not create the directory structure. Only the file.

You will need to add logic to your script to test if the *month* directory exists. If not, use [`mkdir()`](https://www.php.net/mkdir) first.

```
if (!is_dir('upload/promotions/' . $month)) {
  // dir doesn't exist, make it
  mkdir('upload/promotions/' . $month);
}

file_put_contents('upload/promotions/' . $month . '/' . $image, $contents_data);
```

**Update:** `mkdir()` accepts a third parameter of `$recursive` which will create *any* missing directory structure. Might be useful if you need to create multiple directories.

Example with recursive and directory permissions set to 777:

```
mkdir('upload/promotions/' . $month, 0777, true);
```

Comment: In addition: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4134734/6263942 if you have problems creating directories with `0777` permission.

Answer (score 13):

modification of above answer to make it a bit more generic, (automatically detects and creates folder from arbitrary filename on system slashes)

ps previous answer is awesome

```
/**
 * create file with content, and create folder structure if doesn't exist 
 * @param String $filepath
 * @param String $message
 */
function forceFilePutContents ($filepath, $message){
    try {
        $isInFolder = preg_match("/^(.*)\/([^\/]+)$/", $filepath, $filepathMatches);
        if($isInFolder) {
            $folderName = $filepathMatches[1];
            $fileName = $filepathMatches[2];
            if (!is_dir($folderName)) {
                mkdir($folderName, 0777, true);
            }
        }
        file_put_contents($filepath, $message);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "ERR: error writing '$message' to '$filepath', ". $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely unnecessary...You could just check if directory exists. If not call `mkdir($fileDestinationDir, 0777, true);`. And then call `file_put_contents`. While *NIX systems use `/` as directory separator, Windows doesn't care and you can do `mkdir('/path/with/forward/slashes')` without any problems.

Comment: works ok for me

Answer (score 4):

i have Been Working on the laravel Project With the Crud Generator and this Method is not Working

@aqm so i have created my own function

> PHP Way

```
function forceFilePutContents (string $fullPathWithFileName, string $fileContents)
    {
        $exploded = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$fullPathWithFileName);

        array_pop($exploded);

        $directoryPathOnly = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$exploded);

        if (!file_exists($directoryPathOnly)) 
        {
            mkdir($directoryPathOnly,0775,true);
        }
        file_put_contents($fullPathWithFileName, $fileContents);    
    }
```

> LARAVEL WAY

Don't forget to add at top of the file

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`

```
function forceFilePutContents (string $fullPathWithFileName, string $fileContents)
    {
        $exploded = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$fullPathWithFileName);

        array_pop($exploded);

        $directoryPathOnly = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$exploded);

        if (!File::exists($directoryPathOnly)) 
        {
            File::makeDirectory($directoryPathOnly,0775,true,false);
        }
        File::put($fullPathWithFileName,$fileContents);
    }
```

Comment: `$directoryPathOnly = dirname($fullPathWithFileName)` ;)

Answer (score 3):

I created an simpler answer from @Manojkiran.A and @Savageman. This function can be used as drop-in replacement for file_put_contents. It doesn't support context parameter but I think should be enough for most cases. I hope this helps some people. Happy coding! :)

```
function force_file_put_contents (string $pathWithFileName, mixed $data, int $flags = 0) {
  $dirPathOnly = dirname($pathWithFileName);
  if (!file_exists($dirPathOnly)) {
    mkdir($dirPathOnly, 0775, true); // folder permission 0775
  }
  file_put_contents($pathWithFileName, $data, $flags);
}
```

Comment: There is an error in your code, $directoryPathOnly should be $dirPathOnly

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for point out mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Laravel solution:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

// If the directory does not exist, it will be create
// Works recursively, with unlimited number of subdirectories
File::ensureDirectoryExists('my/super/directory');

// Write file content
File::put('my/super/directory/my-file.txt', 'this is file content');
```

Answer (score -4):

I wrote a function you might like. It is called forceDir(). It basicaly checks whether the dir you want exists. If so, it does nothing. If not, it will create the directory. A reason to use this function, instead of just mkdir, is that this function can create nexted folders as well.. For example ('upload/promotions/januari/firstHalfOfTheMonth'). Just add the path to the desired dir_path.

```
function forceDir($dir){
    if(!is_dir($dir)){
        $dir_p = explode('/',$dir);
        for($a = 1 ; $a <= count($dir_p) ; $a++){
            @mkdir(implode('/',array_slice($dir_p,0,$a)));  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also just add `true` as the third parameter to mkdir().