# Apache permissions, PHP file create on Arch Lamp Setup

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, archlinux

It seems that I cannot upload and create files in my Arch Linux Lamp Setup. When I check my desired folder  permissions , I get :

```
ls -ldh thumbnails/
drwxrwxrwx 5 ytsejam http 4.0K Jun 13 12:33 thumbnails/
```

I check my apache user by php whoami()  result is  "http"
and /etc/group have those entries

```
http:x:33:ytsejam
users:x:100:http
wheel:x:10:root,ytsejam.
```

I cant see any error on `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or access_log. 
Here is error when I upload the file

```
ErrorException

file_put_contents(/home/ytsejam/public_html/projemiz/public/uploads/img/posts/thumbnails/213/thumb-flam1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

When I create the folder manually I can get success on upload. It is a permissions error but I don't know how to fix it. Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create directories (folders) with `file_put_contents`.

See [PHP, Creating a folder when I run file_put_contents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372179/php-creating-a-folder-when-i-run-file-put-contents)