# Create folder tree structure based on url PHP

Tags: php, github, mkdir

I am pulling some raw files content from git  and displaying those on my website. 
So that I dont ping github on every load I cache those files contents in to a simple txt files.

All nice and dandy. But I am caching them all in to a same folder.

What I would like to do is create the actual folder tree from this url

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/master/index.html
```

so that my cached files gets saved as

```
octocat
--Spoon-Knife
---master
----test.txt
```

Any fast way of creating such folder structure based on the url?
Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372179/php-creating-a-folder-when-i-run-file-put-contents second answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work, it extracts the directory structure with [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function, and creates nested directories ( if they don't already exist ).

```
$url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/master/index.html';

$path = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH );
$dir = __DIR__ . dirname($path) . '/';

if ( !file_exists( $dir ) ) {
    mkdir( $dir, 0777, true );
}
```