# How to upload base64 image by creating directory and upload

Tags: php, image, file-upload, image-uploading

I am want to upload image into following folder structure:

```
/var/www/html/project/public/upload/userimage/2016/04/07/thumbnail/image.png
                                               ^   ^  ^
                                            Year Month Date
```

and I have wrote this code:

```
$Day = date('d'); // Get date
$Month = date('m'); // Get month
$Year = date('Y'); // Get year

$data = $_POST['base64']; // Get base64 image data

$imageName = hash('ripemd160', time()).'.png';

if (!file_exists(public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.$Year.'/'.$Month.'/'.$Day.'/thumbnail')) {
    mkdir(public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.$Year.'/'.$Month.'/'.$Day.'/thumbnail', 0777, true);
}
$url = public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.$Year.'/'.$Month.'/'.$Day.'/thumbnail/'.$imageName;

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents($url.'/'.$imageName, $data);
```

and getting this error:

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/project/project/public/upload/userimage/2016/04/07/thumbnail/8b38eb25ce97d428afcd80d6ddcd16b8ca266a52.png/8b38eb25ce97d428afcd80d6ddcd16b8ca266a52.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I just want to upload image to directory folder with generating folder `Year -> Month -> Date` if `Year/Month/Date` is changed.

I will appreciate if you help me to make my code more proper :)

Thanks.

Comment: I dunno whether it works, but once try creating the directory first using `mkdir` function and then upload files into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your directory doesn't exists.

```
$url = public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.$Year.'/'.$Month.'/'.$Day.'/thumbnail/'.$imageName;
#                                                                                 ----------
file_put_contents($url.'/'.$imageName, $data);
#                          ----------
```

You create this directory:

```
/My/New/Directory
```

Then you try to write this file:

```
/My/New/Directory/Image.jpg/Image.jpg
```

Use this command:

```
file_put_contents( $url , $data );
```

---

A general suggestion: use variables instead of repeat concatenate patterns, especially if you have long concatenations. Your code is more clear, code maintenance is easier and the risk of typos is lower:

```
$dirPath = public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.$Year.'/'.$Month.'/'.$Day.'/thumbnail';
if( !file_exists( $dirPath ) )      
    mkdir( $dirPath, 0777, true );
}
$filePath = $dirPath.'/'.$imageName;
(...)
file_put_contents( $filePath , $data );
```

Answer (score 1):

`file_put_contents` does not create directory:
So use:

```
if (!is_dir('upload/usersimage/'.$Year.'/'.$Month.'/'.$Day.'' . $month)) {
    mkdir('upload/usersimage/'.$Year.'/'.$Month.'/'.$Day.' . $month);
}
```

See here: [Creating a folder when I run file_put_contents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372179/creating-a-folder-when-i-run-file-put-contents)