# How to get the active workspace in vscode's Multi-root Workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to get the active workspace in Multi-root Workspaces.
I write a extension for vscode, and I use this code to check is current workspace is Multi-root.

```
let wsfolders = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders
!wsfolders  no 
wsfolders.length != 1   Multi-root
```

After this, How can I find which is the active workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Use

> **vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder**(uri: Uri): WorkspaceFolder | undefined
>
> Returns the workspace folder that contains a given uri.
>
> - returns undefined when the given uri doesn't match any workspace folder
> - returns the input when the given uri is a workspace folder itself

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of an "active" workspace in VS Code, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceFolder.

Maybe your underlying requirement is to find out which workspace folder the "active editor" (the editor that is currently focussed) belongs to.
In that case you can use the path of active editor's document and compare it to the paths of all workspace folders to find the matching one, if any.

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import * as path from "path";

if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor) {

    const activeEditorPath = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.path;
    
    const matchingWorkspace = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders?.find(
        (wsFolder) => {
            const relative = path.relative(wsFolder.uri.fsPath, activeEditorPath);
            return relative && !relative.startsWith('..') && !path.isAbsolute(relative);
        }
    );      
}
```

(The function checking the paths was taken from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45242825/15247754))

Comment: Instead of implementing the the "find workspace logic" manually as in my answer, you should rather use the VS Code API cited in @rioV8 's answer.