# Create a folder named as the username of logged in user using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code which use output.txt to store and retrieve some content. Currently, this output.txt file is in the same directory as this PHP file and other relevant files.

```
<?php include('session.php') ;?>

<?php

if(isset($loggedin_session)){ 

//session is set, the user is logged in 
}
else{

header("Location: index.php");
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Please Login first")';
echo '</script>';
exit;
//die("Redirecting to index.php");

}

//function test() 
 $message = false;
 if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $message = $_POST['message'];
 } 

 $descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
);  
$process = proc_open('python filename.py', $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null); 

if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], "$message\n"); // input   

    fclose($pipes[0]); // has to be closed before reading output!

    $output = "";
    while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
        $output = file_get_contents("output.txt");
        $output = "$output\n" . fgets($pipes[1]);
        file_put_contents("output.txt", $output);


    }
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($process);  
    echo nl2br ($output);
}
?>
```

output.txt is common to all users. But now I want to have each user their own output.txt. For this, I want to automatically create a folder with the username of logged in user and inside it store the output.txt . I am using MySQL database for users logging.

Is this possible? Or is there any other way to achieve this target. Any suggestion or reference material regarding this would be a great help.

Comment: This is very dangerous and could leave you open to command-line injection attacks if you are not *extremely* careful or if you don’t know exactly what you’re doing. You should not pass user input directly into shell commands or file/path names even if you do know what you’re doing. In fact, doing those things would pretty much prove that you are in over your head.

Comment: For whatever the reason, why not store the data of those output files in the database as well ?

Comment: He is not letting user input define the path, he is creating a folder based on the user pulled from the DB.  Not sure why that is an issue?

Comment: You already have your user name here?  $loggedin_session?  Or in SESSION?  Where exactly are you running into issues here?

Comment: @Bleach In this very particular case it looks like everything's set properly, but all it takes is a moment of inattention and you can create huge problems. Handle functions like `proc_open` with the utmost respect, as if they're radioactive material, because they can and will ruin your life if you're not careful.

Comment: @Bleach I am not able to automatically create a folder named as username

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372179/creating-a-folder-when-i-run-file-put-contents